# remove the space between images in css & html

Tags: html, css

i have this code which displayed six photos, each two in one row, however they have different sizes
what i want to fill the empty spaces by the photo which will be under it

here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class='section-headline'>The Timeline</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row timeline-container">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-1">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/pioneer.jpg" width='240' alt="Pioneer 0" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Pioneer 0</h3>
                            <time>17 August 1958</time>
                            <p>Pioneer 0 was a failed United States space probe that was designed to </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-2">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/luna-1.jpg" width='240' alt="Luna E-1 No.1"
                            class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Luna E-1 No.1</h3>
                            <time>23 September 1958</time>
                            <p>Luna E-1 No.1, sometimes identified by NASA as Luna 1958A, was a Soviet Luna E-1
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-3">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/apollo-11.jpg" width='240' alt="Apollo 11"
                            class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Apollo 11</h3>
                            <time>16 July 1969</time>
                            <p>Apollo 11 was the spaceflight that landed the first two humans on the Moon. Mission
                                lunar surface before rejoining Columbia in lunar orbit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-4">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/luna-24.jpg" width='240' alt="Luna 24" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Luna 24</h3>
                            <time>9 August 1976</time>
                            <p>Luna 24 was an unmanned space mission of the Soviet Union's Luna program. The last
                               
                                (10,600 lb).</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-5">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/hiten.jpg" width='240' alt="Hiten" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>Hiten</h3>
                            <time>24 January 1990</time>
                            <p>The Hiten Spacecraft, given the English name Celestial Maiden and known before launch
                                a
                                delta-v deficit of 50 m/s, resulting in an apogee of only 290,000 km.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="timeline-item timeline-6">
                        <img src="/images/timeline/artemis.jpg" width='240' alt="ARTEMIS" class="timeline-item-image">
                        <div class="timeline-item-content">
                            <h3>ARTEMIS</h3>
                            <time>Spring 2010</time>
                            <p>The Time History of Events and Macroscale Interactions during Substorms (THEMIS)

   
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

what i want is to have zero spaces between each photo

i have tried `margin:0;` but it didnt work also i tried this way it didnt work

```
   .timeline-item {
        width: auto;
        flex: 0 0 50%;
    }
```

Comment: If you right-click on one of the images in a browser and choose "Inspect" then it will bring up the browser's developer tools. You might want to move the tool window somewhere more convenient. Look for a tab named something like "Layout" or "Computed" and have a look for non-zero values of margin, border, and padding. You can navigate to other elements until you find the one(s) which are contributing to the spacing.

Comment: It may not be "margins" at all which are producing the output.  You appear to be using Bootstrap or something similar.  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?